# How to reference the "second-child" and "third-child" on css?

Tags: html, css

I don't know how to reference the second and third child on css.

I tried change the first per second and third but don't work.

I only can reference the first and last-child

```
keypad :first-child :nth-child(1){
    background-color: black;
}

keypad :last-child :nth-child(3){
    background-color: #b22222;
}
```

Comment: `.classname :nth-child(3)` works fine.

Comment: Do you really have a `<keypad>` element? If it's `class="keypad"` then the selector should be `.keypad`

Answer (score 1):

To refer to a specific child from a parent element, do it like this

`.keypad:nth-child(2)`

Answer (score 0):

First, in your css you should set `.` if `keypad` is the name of a `class` or `#` if it is an `id`. Then use `:nth-child` to refer the order of a child:

```css
.keypad:nth-child(2){
    background-color: black;
}

.keypad:nth-child(3){
    background-color: #b22222;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="keypad">1</div>
  <div class="keypad">2</div>
  <div class="keypad">3</div>
  <div class="keypad">4</div>
  <div class="keypad">5</div>
  <div class="keypad">6</div>
  <div class="keypad">7</div>
  <div class="keypad">8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have not used the class(.) or Id identifier(#) when calling the CSS element use :

```
.keypad:nth-child(2){....}
```

for class selectors and

```
#keypad:nth-child(2){....}
```

for Id selectors